# Facebook Marketing API ProductAudience doesn't save some values

Tags: php, facebook, api, methods

I'm facing the following:

1. I create a pixel (use it in project: ViewProduct, AddToBasket & Purchase)
2. Create a Catalog + create products feed + create product sets
3. Implement ProductAudience to create Audience on Facebook.

Everything until then works just great, but when I go to Facebook, and navigate to the product audience, It doesn't have any data that I've set while creating the Audience. (eg. PIXEL_ID, PRODUCT_SET_ID, INCLUSIONS & EXCLUSIONS are not set)

That's how my code look like:

```
    use FacebookAds\Object\ProductAudience;
    use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\ProductAudienceFields;

    $productAudience = new ProductAudience($this->id, <myFacebookAdAccountId>);
    $audienceData = [
        ProductAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID => <myPixelId>,
        ProductAudienceFields::PRODUCT_SET_ID => <myProductSetId>,
        ProductAudienceFields::NAME => 'Name for the audience',
    ];
    if (count($this->inclusions)) $audienceData[ProductAudienceFields::INCLUSIONS] = $this->inclusions;
    if (count($this->exclusions)) $audienceData[ProductAudienceFields::EXCLUSIONS] = $this->exclusions;
    $productAudience->setData($audienceData);
    return $productAudience->create();
```

So I'm wondering, what am I doing wrong? Hope to get some guidelines... Have lost already one working day on trying to fix it without any result.

I also tried to retrieve the data trough API:

```
$productAudience = new ProductAudience($this->id);
return $productAudience->read([
    ProductAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID,
    ProductAudienceFields::NAME,
    ProductAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION,
]);
```

The following object is been returned:

```
#data: array:7 [
    "id" => "6047126484024"
    "name" => "Name for the audience"
    "description" => null
    "product_set_id" => null
    "pixel_id" => null
    "inclusions" => null
    "exclusions" => null
]
```

The values are set to null as well... Version of API I'm using is 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution for my problem

```
$productAudience = new ProductAudience($this->id);
$productAudience->read([
    ProductAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID,
    ProductAudienceFields::NAME,
    ProductAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION,
    'data_source',
]);
```

It doesn't set the values, so the product_set_id and few other fields ares still set to null, but we get all the fields in 'creation_params' object.

I also created a helper function that sets the needed values:

```
private function fieldsFromDataSourceToObject(ProductAudience &$productAudience)
{
    $creationParams = json_decode($productAudience->data_source['creation_params']);
    $productAudience->setData([
        ProductAudienceFields::PRODUCT_SET_ID => $creationParams->product_set_id,
        ProductAudienceFields::INCLUSIONS => json_decode($creationParams->inclusions, true),
        ProductAudienceFields::EXCLUSIONS => json_decode($creationParams->exclusions, true),
    ]);
}
```

So after reading existing product audience, I just call the helper function with response as param

```
$this->fieldsFromDataSourceToObject($productAudience);
```

Hope this solution saves someones time.